# Why would the mean and standard deviation of the first and second derivatives of a signal (e.g. EDA) be useful?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, exploratory-data-analysis

When analysing a signal, e.g. EDA, I intuitively understand why one would want to determine the mean and standard deviation of the signal. The mean would tell us the average value of the EDA signal, whereas the standard deviation would tell us the deviation from this average value.

I've seen examples of exploratory data analysis where the analyst also computes the mean and standard deviation of the first and second derivatives of the same signal. Why would one need these (in practice)? What would this info tell us?

I know that the first derivative of a signal would tell us the rate of change of the signal. But, intuitively, why would we need the average (and the deviation from the average) of the rate of change of the signal? What are examples where these features would be useful to analyse or draw conclusions from the data? What about the mean and standard deviation of the second derivative?

Comment: "EDA" on this site usually refers to "Exploratory Data Analysis" (a term you actually use but don't seem to equate with "EDA").  What do *you* mean by it?  Could you define what you mean by a "signal"?  Its meaning can vary considerably depending on the application.

Comment: That raises the question of what you mean by its derivative, then.